# NetworkBoundResource with Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Do you have any ideas how to implement repository pattern with [**NetworkBoundResource**](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt) and Kotlin coroutines? I know we can launch a coroutine withing a GlobalScope, but it may lead to coroutine leak. I would like to pass a **viewModelScope** as a parameter, but it is a bit tricky, when it comes to implementation (because my repository doesn't know a CoroutineScope of any ViewModel).

```
abstract class NetworkBoundResource<ResultType, RequestType>
@MainThread constructor(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
) {

    private val result = MediatorLiveData<Resource<ResultType>>()

    init {
        result.value = Resource.loading(null)
        @Suppress("LeakingThis")
        val dbSource = loadFromDb()
        result.addSource(dbSource) { data ->
            result.removeSource(dbSource)
            if (shouldFetch(data)) {
                fetchFromNetwork(dbSource)
            } else {
                result.addSource(dbSource) { newData ->
                    setValue(Resource.success(newData))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @MainThread
    private fun setValue(newValue: Resource<ResultType>) {
        if (result.value != newValue) {
            result.value = newValue
        }
    }

    private fun fetchFromNetwork(dbSource: LiveData<ResultType>) {
        val apiResponse = createCall()
        result.addSource(dbSource) { newData ->
            setValue(Resource.loading(newData))
        }
        result.addSource(apiResponse) { response ->
            result.removeSource(apiResponse)
            result.removeSource(dbSource)
            when (response) {
                is ApiSuccessResponse -> {
                    coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        saveCallResult(processResponse(response))

                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            result.addSource(loadFromDb()) { newData ->
                                setValue(Resource.success(newData))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                is ApiEmptyResponse -> {
                    coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        result.addSource(loadFromDb()) { newData ->
                            setValue(Resource.success(newData))
                        }
                    }
                }

                is ApiErrorResponse -> {
                    onFetchFailed()
                    result.addSource(dbSource) { newData ->
                        setValue(Resource.error(response.errorMessage, newData))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, the repository should expose `suspend` functions, or return `Channel`/`Flow` objects, depending on the nature of the API. The actual coroutines are then set up in the viewmodel. `LiveData` gets introduced by the viewmodel, not the repository.

Comment: @CommonsWare So you propose to rewrite NetworkBoundResource to return actual data (or Resource<T>), without using LiveData in it and in repository?

Comment: You are the one who wants to use `NetworkBoundResource`. My comments are more general: IMHO, a Kotlin repository implementation should expose coroutines-related APIs.

Comment: I'd love to thank you all guys to help me with this question and various answers. And thanks to @CommonsWare whose hint helped me making my code better (again)

Comment: @CommonsWare so you advise against using Room Database with LiveData?

Comment: I would phrase it more as a personal preference. `LiveData` lacks the power of either RxJava or Kotlin coroutines. `LiveData` is very nice for the "last mile" communications to the activity or fragment, and it was designed with that in mind. And for tiny apps, if you want to skip repositories and just have a `ViewModel` talk straight to a `RoomDatabase`, `LiveData` is fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@N1hk answer works right, this is just a different implementation that doesn't use the `flatMapConcat` operator (it is marked as `FlowPreview` at this moment)

```
@FlowPreview
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
abstract class NetworkBoundResource<ResultType, RequestType> {

    fun asFlow() = flow {
        emit(Resource.loading(null))

        val dbValue = loadFromDb().first()
        if (shouldFetch(dbValue)) {
            emit(Resource.loading(dbValue))
            when (val apiResponse = fetchFromNetwork()) {
                is ApiSuccessResponse -> {
                    saveNetworkResult(processResponse(apiResponse))
                    emitAll(loadFromDb().map { Resource.success(it) })
                }
                is ApiErrorResponse -> {
                    onFetchFailed()
                    emitAll(loadFromDb().map { Resource.error(apiResponse.errorMessage, it) })
                }
            }
        } else {
            emitAll(loadFromDb().map { Resource.success(it) })
        }
    }

    protected open fun onFetchFailed() {
        // Implement in sub-classes to handle errors
    }

    @WorkerThread
    protected open fun processResponse(response: ApiSuccessResponse<RequestType>) = response.body

    @WorkerThread
    protected abstract suspend fun saveNetworkResult(item: RequestType)

    @MainThread
    protected abstract fun shouldFetch(data: ResultType?): Boolean

    @MainThread
    protected abstract fun loadFromDb(): Flow<ResultType>

    @MainThread
    protected abstract suspend fun fetchFromNetwork(): ApiResponse<RequestType>
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to emit Resource.error in ApiErrorResponse case?

Comment: What retrofit serve return type should be?

Comment: @MahmoodAli suspend fun someData(@Query/@Path): ApiResponse<List<Postitems>> ... manage it according to your data

Comment: This approach does not emit DB updates while loading is in progress, which can be necessary sometimes

Answer (score 31):

**Update (2020-05-27):**

A way which is more idiomatic to the Kotlin language than my previous examples, uses the Flow APIs, and borrows from Juan's answer can be represented as a standalone function like the following:

```
inline fun <ResultType, RequestType> networkBoundResource(
    crossinline query: () -> Flow<ResultType>,
    crossinline fetch: suspend () -> RequestType,
    crossinline saveFetchResult: suspend (RequestType) -> Unit,
    crossinline onFetchFailed: (Throwable) -> Unit = { Unit },
    crossinline shouldFetch: (ResultType) -> Boolean = { true }
) = flow<Resource<ResultType>> {
    emit(Resource.Loading(null))
    val data = query().first()

    val flow = if (shouldFetch(data)) {
        emit(Resource.Loading(data))

        try {
            saveFetchResult(fetch())
            query().map { Resource.Success(it) }
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            onFetchFailed(throwable)
            query().map { Resource.Error(throwable, it) }
        }
    } else {
        query().map { Resource.Success(it) }
    }

    emitAll(flow)
}
```

The above code can be called from a class, e.g. a Repository, like so:

```
fun getItems(request: MyRequest): Flow<Resource<List<MyItem>>> {
    return networkBoundResource(
        query = { dao.queryAll() },
        fetch = { retrofitService.getItems(request) },
        saveFetchResult = { items -> dao.insert(items) }
    )
}
```

**Original answer:**

This is how I've been doing it using the `livedata-ktx` artifact; no need to pass in any CoroutineScope. The class also uses just one type instead of two (e.g. ResultType/RequestType) since I always end up using an adapter elsewhere for mapping those.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.liveData
import androidx.lifecycle.map
import nihk.core.Resource

// Adapted from: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines
abstract class NetworkBoundResource<T> {

    fun asLiveData() = liveData<Resource<T>> {
        emit(Resource.Loading(null))

        if (shouldFetch(query())) {
            val disposable = emitSource(queryObservable().map { Resource.Loading(it) })

            try {
                val fetchedData = fetch()
                // Stop the previous emission to avoid dispatching the saveCallResult as `Resource.Loading`.
                disposable.dispose()
                saveFetchResult(fetchedData)
                // Re-establish the emission as `Resource.Success`.
                emitSource(queryObservable().map { Resource.Success(it) })
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                onFetchFailed(e)
                emitSource(queryObservable().map { Resource.Error(e, it) })
            }
        } else {
            emitSource(queryObservable().map { Resource.Success(it) })
        }
    }

    abstract suspend fun query(): T
    abstract fun queryObservable(): LiveData<T>
    abstract suspend fun fetch(): T
    abstract suspend fun saveFetchResult(data: T)
    open fun onFetchFailed(exception: Exception) = Unit
    open fun shouldFetch(data: T) = true
}
```

Like @CommonsWare said in the comments, however, it'd be nicer to just expose a `Flow<T>`. Here's what I've tried coming up with to do that. Note that I haven't used this code in production, so buyer beware.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import nihk.core.Resource

abstract class NetworkBoundResource<T> {

    fun asFlow(): Flow<Resource<T>> = flow {
        val flow = query()
            .onStart { emit(Resource.Loading<T>(null)) }
            .flatMapConcat { data ->
                if (shouldFetch(data)) {
                    emit(Resource.Loading(data))

                    try {
                        saveFetchResult(fetch())
                        query().map { Resource.Success(it) }
                    } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
                        onFetchFailed(throwable)
                        query().map { Resource.Error(throwable, it) }
                    }
                } else {
                    query().map { Resource.Success(it) }
                }
            }

        emitAll(flow)
    }

    abstract fun query(): Flow<T>
    abstract suspend fun fetch(): T
    abstract suspend fun saveFetchResult(data: T)
    open fun onFetchFailed(throwable: Throwable) = Unit
    open fun shouldFetch(data: T) = true
}
```

Comment: The `Flow` code will make the network request again when the data in the database changes, I posted a new answer that shows how to handle it

Comment: In my testing I put a breakpoint inside the `flatMapConcat` block and also within the `query().map { Resource.Success(it) }` block, then inserted an item into the database. Only the latter breakpoint got hit. In other words, the network request doesn't get made again when the data in the database changes.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint here `if (shouldFetch(data))` you will see that it is called twice. The first time when you get the results from the database and the second one when `saveFetchResult(fetch())` is called

Comment: And if you think about it that's what you want when you use a `Flow`. You are saving something in the database and you want Room to let you know about that change and call your `flatMapConcat` code again. 
You were not using a `Flow<T>` and using `T` instead if you don't want that behavior

Comment: Maybe you are not returning a `Flow<List<T>>` from the database, and you should. Check https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130428884

Comment: I am returning a `Flow<List<T>>` from the database, though.

Comment: I made a pure-Kotlin gist that mimics how Room emits its flows. Feel free to copy and paste and run it. You'll see what I mean by the `flatMapConcat` only being called once (watch for line 12):
https://gist.github.com/nihk/1539b20b13c1a484149764f92e053eba

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood the code. The `flatMapConcat` will return a new flow to be observed, so the initial flow will no longer be called.  
Both answers behave in the same way, so I will keep mine just as a different way to implement it.  
Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Could you please guide how to use (your latest) inline function in repository? do i need to create that function for every method in repository or just once like class?

Comment: @DrMagneto you can put that function once into a standalone .kt file. Repositories can call it as they see fit

Comment: @DrMagneto I've added an example of its use to my answer.

Comment: @N1hk what if the fetch request is also returning Flow, how to save the stream of data emitted by the flow?

Comment: @N1hk Can you explain how to use this class? I'm using NetworkBoundResource (the flow version) in my repository function but after calling the function multiple times the map of the database felow will trigger multiple times.

Comment: @hosseinAmini Make sure you're cancelling any active `Job`s if you collect the Flow more than once. In a ViewModel you can keep a stateful `Job` field that gets cancelled/assigned every time you call the Flow.

Comment: @N1hk in my ViewModel I'm using viewModelScope.launch{} to call the flow. You mean I should create a Job() field and give it to the viewModelScope.launch() like this viewModelScope.launch(job) and cancel/assign this job by calling the method?

Comment: How would you use the `onFetchFailed` callback? Pass a lambda from the ViewModel to the repository?

Comment: Also, `Loading` does not emit database updates. This can be a problem if the database entry can change for other reasons (like tapping a bookmark icon in my case)

Comment: @FlorianWalther regarding your 2nd question, I gave an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65984833/2997980

Comment: @N1hk How do we handle exception thrown by query() function? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Kotlin Coroutine. I just come across this problem this week.

I think if you go with the repository pattern as mentioned in the post above, my opinion is feeling free to pass a **CoroutineScope** into the **NetworkBoundResource**.  The **CoroutineScope** can be one of the parameters of the function in the **Repository**, which returns a LiveData, like:

```
suspend fun getData(scope: CoroutineScope): LiveDate<T>
```

Pass the build-in scope **viewmodelscope** as the CoroutineScope when calling **getData()** in your ViewModel, so **NetworkBoundResource** will work within the **viewmodelscope** and be bound with the Viewmodel's lifecycle. The coroutine in the **NetworkBoundResource** will be cancelled when **ViewModel** is dead, which would be a benefit.

To use the build-in scope **viewmodelscope**, don't forget add below in your build.gradle.

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01'
```